# objects are not stored into objectbox (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-objectbox

So Im trying to save an object(with only one String attribute) in the ObjectBox. The ObjectBox is called favoriteBox. With the onLongPress-function im trying to put the object in the box. In the initState-function im trying to put all the objects (more specific: the string attributes of each object) in to a nested list.

My problem now is that after calling the onLongPress-function and putting the object in the favoriteBox, the favoritBox is null according to the Debugger.
Im not sure where my mistake is.

```
class _GridViewJokesState extends State<GridViewJokes> {
  late int seasonsListIndex;
  List<List<String?>> seasonsList = seasons;

  final toast = FToast();
  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late SeasonProvider seasonProvider;

  Store? _store;
  Box<FavoritesEntity>? favoritesBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    toast.init(context);
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) {
      _store = Store(getObjectBoxModel(), directory: dir.path + "/objectbox");
    });
    favoritesBox = _store?.box<FavoritesEntity>();
    seasonsList[5] =
        favoritesBox?.getAll().map((e) => e.quoteName).toList() ?? [];
  }
```

```
void onLongPress(listTileIndex) {
    if (seasonProvider.seasonPicked) {
      seasonsList[5].add(seasonsList[seasonsListIndex][listTileIndex]);
      favoritesBox?.put(FavoritesEntity(
          quoteName: seasonsList[seasonsListIndex][listTileIndex]));
      toast.showToast(
          child: buildToast("Zu Favoriten hinzugefügt"),
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM);
    }
```

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
class FavoritesEntity {
  FavoritesEntity({required this.quoteName});

  int id = 0;
  String? quoteName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the code does not await the Future that returns the application Documents directory before accessing `store`. So `store` will still be null and the following line that gets a box does nothing.

```
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) {
  _store = Store(getObjectBoxModel(), directory: dir.path + "/objectbox");
});
// store is still null here:
favoritesBox = _store?.box<FavoritesEntity>();
```

You can either move the box get code into the `then()` closure. Or, as we recommend, init Store into a global variable using a helper class in the `main` function. [See our examples](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/tree/main/objectbox/example/flutter/objectbox_demo_relations/lib).